# SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement Generates extra spaces

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to create a method based on json value.
this is my json :

```
"handler": {
            "logic": "var response = new IsoMessage(context.Request.Id + 10); \n for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)\n if ((i != 64) && context.Request.Has(i)) \n response[i] = context.Request[i]; \n\n await Task.Delay(200); \n\n await context.SourceLink.SendAsync(response);"

        }
```

when it is parsed, normalized with whitespace ,and add to a method, the item that is print is not in a good format. How can I fix it?

This is the code for method syntax creation:

```
var syntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement(logic).NormalizeWhitespace(); 
    
// Create a method public async Task ProcessAsync(IncomingMessageContext context)
var methodDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(typeof(Task).Name), "ProcessAsync")
        .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
        .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.AsyncKeyword))
        .WithParameterList(parameterList)
        .WithBody(SyntaxFactory.Block(syntax));
```

before printing, it is the code:

> var code = @namespace.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();

The output is like this:

```
public async Task ProcessAsync(Nikan.Channels.IncomingMessageContext context)
        {
            var response = new IsoMessage(context.Request.Id + 10); for  ( int  i  =  0 ;  i < 128 ;  i ++ ) if  ( ( i != 64 ) && context . Request . Has ( i ) ) response [ i ]  =  context . Request [ i ] ;  await  Task . Delay ( 200 ) ;  await  context . SourceLink . SendAsync ( response ) ;
        }
```

**There is a lot of space in function and no newline is applied. :(**

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that is being parsed contains *multiple* statements instead of a single statement. If you notice the first statement:

```
var response = new IsoMessage(context.Request.Id + 10);
```

is formatted correctly and doesn't look like this:

```
var  response  =  new  IsoMessage ( context . Request . Id + 10 ) ;
```

Therefore, when using `SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement()` if your code consists of multiple statements then surround all of the statements with a pair of curly braces (`{...}`) and cast to `BlockSyntax` which will subsequently parse the code as a "block":

```
var syntax = (BlockSyntax) SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement("{" + logic + "}");

// ...additional code transformations that adds `ProcessAync()`, etc....

var code = @namespace.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
```

Also in the method declaration remove `SyntaxFactory.Block()` since it should now cast to the correct type:

```
.WithBody(syntax);
```

Then your code should output this:

```
public async Task ProcessAsync(Nikan.Channels.IncomingMessageContext context)
{
    var response = new IsoMessage(context.Request.Id + 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        if ((i != 64) && context.Request.Has(i))
            response[i] = context.Request[i];
    await Task.Delay(200);
    await context.SourceLink.SendAsync(response);
}
```

Comment: var syntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseCompilationUnit(logic); 

var methodDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(typeof(Task).Name), "ProcessAsync").WithBody(SyntaxFactory.Block(syntax));


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Has The Error : 
can not convert from 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax' to 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxList<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.StatementSyntax>'

Comment: @HappyDeveloper I've updated my answer with a solution that should now work.

Comment: than you @Ray, but because the syntax of logic is going to use in the body of method, the method body will have two braces in this way.
------------------------------------------------------------
var syntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement("{" + logic + "}");
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 var methodDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(typeof(Task).Name), "ProcessAsync")
    .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
    .WithBody(SyntaxFactory.Block(syntax));

Comment: public async override Task ProcessAsync(Nikan.Channels.IncomingMessageContext context)
        {
            {
                var response = new IsoMessage(context.Request.Id + 10);
                for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
                    if ((i != 64) && context.Request.Has(i))
                        response[i] = context.Request[i];
                await Task.Delay(200);
                await context.SourceLink.SendAsync(response);
            }
        }

Comment: if you can see there is two braces for starting and ending of the method

Comment: I cast the parseStatement to (BlockStatement) ! every thing is Ok! thank you @Ray
please add casting to your answer, then I will make it acceptable.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper Awesome that worked. :) Updated my answer with your suggestion.